# Как обновлять контент в реальном времени?

Tags: php, websocket

Как обновлять информацию на странице в реальном времени. Например есть страница которая выводит записи пользователей из базы данных, простая выборка. page.php

Нужно что бы контент на странице page.php обновлялся автоматически как только в базе будет новая запись.

Пытался делать с помощью ratchet push но не смогу установить расширения zmq, выдает ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'React\ZMQ\Context' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\bin\push-server.php:8 Версия php 7.3.11

Надесю на вашу помощь

В гугле искал и не нашел мне нужного ответа и поэтому и задал вопрос тут.

Comment: 1. Страница генерируется и отдаётся клиенту. В странице - HTML, Javascript, картинки и стили. 2. Javascript периодически связывается с сервером и спрашивает, есть ли новые данные. Либо 3. Javascript клиент подписывается на WebSocket уведомления, отсылаемые сервером, о том что данные страницы обновились.

Comment: Все очень круто звучит, но мне бы примеры как это реализовать

Comment: 2-й вышеописанный пример - через ajax переодически опрашиваете базу, и если есть новая строка - обновляете контент.

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev Так тоже делал через setTimeOut но этот вариант не подходит, слишком много запросов с серверу бесполезных. Хотелось бы на websocket-х сделать

Comment: А примеров полно в Интернете, @EmilGasanov.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov в интернете полно примеров как сделать чат но не то, что мне нужно. А мне нужно что бы информация на странице ``page.php`` автоматически обновлялись из базы. Например пользователь смотрит ленту и новые посты добавлялись автоматически. 
Есть ли такая технология типо функция слушает page.php и как только появляется новая инфа обновляет страницу.

Comment: @EmilGasanov, принцип один и тот же. Вам главное установить связь с сервером по каналу, а уже после этого передавать в этот канал что необходимо. Обновление страницы будет делаться Javascript'ом (HTML блок будет вставляться в нужное место). Сервер будет периодически проверять если что-то новое появилось, и отправлять через WebSockets, либо слать через него уведомления аля Laravel Broadcasting (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/broadcasting)

Comment: Можно сделать ajax запрос с ожиданием, а в PHP не отвечать на него сразу, а в цикле делать запрос, пока не появятся новые данные, либо пока не будет достигнуто максимально допустимое время ожидания из php.ini, если данные появились передаем их, если нет сообщаем о таймауте. После чего JS снова делает запрос, и ждет ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Способы получения изменений на сервере в "реальном времени":

1. В браузере из цикла, делать запрос, время от времени. (Затратно для сервера и клиента, не совсем реальное время).
2. WebSocket (Современно, Экономно).
3. Long-polling (Работает везде, Немного затратно для сервера).
4. Push-сервер, Webhook и прочие (специфические).

Для вашей задачи подойдет 2 способ лучше всего, с поддержкой в 2019 году проблем нет.