# Следить за изменением в бд mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Нужно следить за изменением в бд, если есть изменение в таблице, то вывести. Я делаю через ajax, но это нагрузка на бд. Есть какой нибудь другой метод?

Comment: А какую задачу это решает?

Comment: Чат. Но дело в том, что я бы сделал через websocket, но помимо сайта еще и программа.

Comment: И когда пользователь отправляет сообщение с программы, добавляется в бд и отображается на сайте и наоборот

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как обновлять контент в реальном времени?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056115/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Comment: Вот я и говорю. Через websocket сделать не смогу, потому что сообщения отправляются еще и с приложения (добавляются в бд). Если сделать на websocket, то я смогу сделать только на сайте

Comment: Сам MySQL мониторить себя на предмет изменений может, но вот механизма сообщать это наружу у него нет. Посему - либо внешний, локальный для MySQL, сервис, который периодически его опрашивает, и по изменению уведомляет удалённое приложение, либо самописная UDF, которая по факту изменения отсылает уведомление (либо подаёт сигнал пуш-сервису, который уведомляет).

Comment: Хорошо. А каждые сколько секунд опрашивать бд оптимально?

Comment: Чтобы сильной нагрузки не было

Comment: А что мешает из обработчика прямо отправить сообщение в приложуху и на сайт и после этого сохранить в БД, чтобы не опрашивать БД каждую секунду?

Comment: Вот это я не знаю как сделать, программа на c#, и как отправить json в nodejs?

Comment: Я пытался найти решение, что то не нашел или какие то не работающие методы были

Comment: В nodejs проще всего отправить данные обычным http запросом, через curl например. А возможно стоит смотреть в сторону брокеров сообщений, на подобии RabbitMQ